# yii framework: not able to install MongoDb extension for yii2

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

I want to use mongodb with yii framework for that i am trying to install mongodb extension. As per the documentation given at http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-mongodb-index.html  i have already added line ""yiisoft/yii2-mongodb": "~2.0.0"" in my composer.json file.

But whenever i issue command `composer update` to install this extension it gives me below error.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

      Problem 1
        - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.4 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
        - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.3 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
        - yiisoft/yii2-mongodb 2.0.2 requires ext-mongo >=1.5.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.
```

I search a lot on this issue and found one solution here https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-mongodb/issues/18 and here http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/57726-solved-yii2-mongodb/ that suggest to add line `extension=mongo.so` in my /etc/php5/cli/php.ini file . but even after adding line to php.ini file command composer update still gives the same error.

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to install mongodb php extension. after installing this extension it works. here is the link to install mongodb extension https://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php